# How to replace integer?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a (Postgres) table with a integer column filled epoch (time) value. Yesterday, i made a mistake to fill em up with wrong epoch value. Now i need to change all the time column values 1609804800 to 1609718400 The following:

```
time
1609804800
1609804800
1609804800
..goes on..
```

**My expect result:**

```
time
1609718400
1609718400
1609718400
..goes on..
```

My Last query is like:

```
UPDATE 
   history
SET 
   time = REPLACE(time,1609804800,1609718400)
WHERE 
   condition
```

I found some useful things at psql reference page about regexp_replace but got:

> ERROR:  function regexp_replace(integer, unknown, unknown) does not
> exist LINE 1: select distinct regexp_replace(time, '1609804800',
> '16097184...

I would like to replace these integer values with new value. I don't know if this is possible but this will speed up things because I have a total of hundreds of rows. I've tried searching Google and StackOverflow, but I cannot see to come up what it is referring to. Can someone explain how and what it is used for?  Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Date/Time values should be stored in a `timestamp` (or even better: `timestamptz` column). Not as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put your condition in where. and the condition will be  `WHERE time  = 1609804800`.

here template is like `SET Colum_name = value`(with which you want to update)
`WHERE (put your conditions here )` and in your case it is `WHERE  time  = 1609804800`

```
UPDATE history
   SET time = 1609718400
WHERE 
   time  = 1609804800
```

[ref](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update)

Comment: Ah how i missed condition. Its works very well now, thank you!

Comment: @OliviaLundy if this answer work for you. acceptance of the ans will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one more `WHERE` condition as follows:

```
UPDATE history
   SET time = 1609718400
 WHERE time  = 1609804800
   and ...condition...
```